# How to convert facebook Graph date time into c# DateTime

Tags: c#, facebook

I have "2010-12-20T11:36:28+0000".
How do I parse it into DateTime?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a clean way or a dirty way? :)

Comment: I tried the direct: DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2010-12-20T11:36:28+0000");
Which seemed to work. What problems are you having with the conversion?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("2010-12-20T11:36:28+0000");

Works on my machine and parses time zone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) with a [Custom Date and Time Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Tested:

```
var myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2010-12-20T11:36:28+0000", 
                                 @"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ssK",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Having said that, `DateTime.Parse` works perfectly well.

Comment: That format string does not handle the time zone portion. DateTime.Parse will though.

Comment: @chilbacity - Yeah, I realized as I was testing. There doesn't seem to be any custom or standard DateTime format string that will parse that exact format of the time zone portion :(

Comment: I think you can do it with 'K' (i.e. @"yyyy-MM-dd\Thh:mm:ssK"), but that seems to affect the performance a fair bit.

Comment: @chibacity - Quite right. I made the mistake of using the `+` as a literal in the custom format string.

Comment: You need HH not hh. Its 24 hour.

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "2010-12-20T11:36:28+0000";
string start = date.Substring(0, date.IndexOf("T"));
string end = date.Substring(date.IndexOf("T") + 1, date.IndexOf("+") - (date.IndexOf("T") + 1));
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(start +" "+ end);
```

Comment: this is the fast & dirty way :]

Comment: It is only very marginally quicker than using the built-in DateTime.Parse. It makes up for its lack of speed with its dirtiness though ;)

Comment: it doesn't handle the time zone portion.